# How to move data from child form to parent form?

Tags: c#

I have two forms.the parent form is form A. in form A I open Form B.I do something then I want to transfer data to form A.I do not know how to do it.
I try to using public variables but it did not work.

Comment: How does `FormA` open `FormB`? Is it all in a single method in `FormA` and is it modal, or do you store `FormB` in a field? Do the two forms run simultaneously?

Comment: _but it did not work_ - not enough to help. Show code how you create open form B and show what did you tried. And also see duplicated questions

Comment: using `public static` variables may solve your problem.

Comment: @Nofuzy to cheghad khobi...I use Public Properties.

Comment: not simple public properties, change them to `public static` so you can transfer values from one form to another in run-time, without re-creating the target form.

Comment: @Nofuzy I like to learn more about class and oop programming.Do You know any ebook or website?

Comment: @Nofuzy Ok I use Your solution.can You put in answer.

Comment: @SedigheRahimi if your listening in English is good as well as your writing, I suggest you pragimTech videos: www.pragimtech.com/

Comment: this question is mark as duplicated, so there will be no way to submit new answers.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is that Form B raises an event when something of interest happens.  Form A can listen for this event and then update one of its controls.

**If you give more information** I'll be happy to provide an example.

Comment: This is more a comment then an answer. Why courage people to create incomplete questions without any effort for trying to solve it by yourself. I think you even spend more time for answer then OP for question :)

Comment: @Fabio `!false`